# iPhone - layoutSubviews being called when updating subview

Tags: ios, uikit, layoutsubviews

I have a custom view with a grid-like layout.  When I touch each subview I want to animate them.  The superview overrides `layoutSubviews` to create the grid of subviews.

The problem is whenever I change the frame of a subview for animation, the superview's layoutSubviews method is called overwriting the frame and no animation happens.

Why does layoutSubviews get called in this scenario and how can I prevent it?

There are other questions similar to this, but none of them have been properly answered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding a flag property on my superview and then set it to YES from my subview to prevent it from laying out subviews.  Seems very hacky but it works.